# Kindle Fire Contest: Winners Announced

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We have **5 Kindle Fires** for giveaway to 5 Android.StackExchange users who best answer one or several particular unanswered questions posed on this site.

[image]

**The Rules:**

- Leave an answer at one or several of **22 questions in the "Kindle Fire Contest."** These are questions that have been left unanswered for some time, and that may hold relevance to Android users and troubleshooting Googlers into the future. Improve the Internet... earn a chance at a Kindle Fire!
- For every answer you leave that is either accepted or the top upvoted answer on the question, your name will be entered to win a Kindle Fire.
- Results will be calculated and winners will be picked in a random drawing on **Monday, Dec. 5 at 10am EST**.
- Contest participants may answer multiple questions -- in fact, it is in your best interest to do so, as each top answer will increase your chances of winning a Kindle Fire.
- Each participant can only win 1 Kindle Fire. If fewer than 5 participants leave top answers by the deadline, then all second-top answerers will be entered into a random drawing for a Kindle Fire.
- Question askers cannot enter the contest by accepting answers that they have left themselves.

Eligible contest questions can be found below.

Good luck!

---

- [HTML signature in Gmail app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15552/html-signature-in-gmail-app)
- [Dialer app becoming too slow and less responsive](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15317/dialer-app-becoming-too-slow-and-less-responsive)
- [How can I download email attachments only when requested?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/how-can-i-download-email-attachments-only-when-requested)
- [Google Latitude and multiple devices - How to prevent location jumping?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15012/google-latitude-and-multiple-devices-how-to-prevent-location-jumping)
- [Marketplace offers downloads in notifications but when I tap notification none are available](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14934/marketplace-offers-downloads-in-notifications-but-when-i-tap-notification-none-a)
- [How can I change the naming convention of the stock camera/gallery app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13954/how-can-i-change-the-naming-convention-of-the-stock-camera-gallery-app)
- [How can I prevent my screen from turning off while on a phone call?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13343/how-can-i-prevent-my-screen-from-turning-off-while-on-a-phone-call)
- [Media volume issues](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13302/media-volume-issues)
- [How can I mount a USB flash drive on my Acer Iconia?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13094/how-can-i-mount-a-usb-flash-drive-on-my-acer-iconia)
- [Android Packet data shortcut](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12960/android-packet-data-shortcut)
- [Samsung Galaxy 5 Wi-fi stops working: "ar6000 driver fails to load"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12883/samsung-galaxy-5-wi-fi-stops-working-ar6000-driver-fails-to-load)
- [How can data on an unrooted phone be backed up?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12470/how-can-data-on-an-unrooted-phone-be-backed-up)
- [Block all sounds going out through speaker when headphone connected](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10996/block-all-sounds-going-out-through-speaker-when-headphone-connected)
- [Text-to-speech reader for Google Voice SMS text messages?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/text-to-speech-reader-for-google-voice-sms-text-messages)
- [Droid X Turns Itself on Automatically](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10082/droid-x-turns-itself-on-automatically)
- [Multiple USB Storage Devices on Honeycomb](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/multiple-usb-storage-devices-on-honeycomb)
- [How can I fix the Wi-Fi button or prevent Wi-Fi errors when turning it off and back on?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4504/how-can-i-fix-the-wifi-button-or-prevent-wifi-errors-when-turning-it-off-and-bac)
- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4345/how-can-i-prevent-google-talk-from-disconnecting
- [Why does a single MMS message show up as three separate download buttons?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3284/why-does-a-single-mms-message-show-up-as-three-separate-download-buttons)
- [Android Email application dropping profile](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/android-email-application-dropping-profile)
- [How can I prevent applications from running on startup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/158/how-can-i-prevent-applications-from-running-on-startup)
- [How do I change the name of my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-do-i-change-the-name-of-my-android-device)

Comment: I expect Stack Exchange employees are ineligible to win. What about Mods?

Comment: @AlEverett - Mods are eligible!

Comment: There are currently 22 questions [tagged with "Kindle Fire Contest"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle-fire-contest)

Comment: This question was untagged, why?

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12962/flush-clear-dns-cache/16163#16163

Comment: @Martin [OP didn't want it](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/741/can-the-tag-for-the-kindle-fire-contest-be-made-a-mod-only-tag).

Comment: Any rules on international participants?

Comment: @Power-Inside - Everyone (except SE employees) is eligible.

Comment: Will the results be posted here?

Comment: @Martin - see below!

Answer (score 5):

We have winners!

Congratulations to users [**JT703**](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/10035/jt703), [**Martin**](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/10050/martin), [**Flow**](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/440/flow), [**masterjo**](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/10040/masterjo) and [**Erowlin**](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/10027/erowlin), who will each receive a Kindle Fire in the mail.

Of dozens of answers submitted for <s>23</s> 22 eligible questions, 66 answers remain undeleted by moderators today, with 4 marked correct by question askers during the contest period.

19 users were included in the random drawing, with users Martin (5), nonsleepr (2), Eddie (2), and Tom (2) each receiving multiple entries.

Thanks for participating and watch out for another contest soon!

Comment: Congratulations everybody!